# Calling a function in an iFrame in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a problem that is specific to IE9.

We are using Autodesk MapGuide which has a framework of several nested Framesets. I am trying to call a Javascript function that sits within an IFrame that is within the top level frameset. (Please I dont want to discuss the merits or otherwise of framestes here.)

I have adapted some code I found in another thread using Jquery

`window.top.$("#MyIframe")[0].contentWindow.MyFunction();`

This works perfectly in IE7 and IE8, but as soon as I try it in IE9 I get the following error:

> TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'contentWindow': object
>   is null or undefined

I suspect that it is struggling with the framesets and can't find '#MyIframe'.

Is there some other format I can try to get around this? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where would you like to discuss the merits or otherwise of framesets?

Comment: That's a whole other problem ;-)